# add a collection of MessageData objects to a message

Tags: c#, masstransit

I'm trying to send a message containing a collection of MessageData<byte[]>. I'm using MassTransit.MessageData.Enchilada package as MessageData repository. But when I try to get the value of the MessageData in the consuming service I get an exception.

**MassTransit.MessageDataException: The message data was not loaded.**

Message

```
    public interface ISendMail
    {
        MessageData<byte[]> Attachment { get; }
        MessageData<byte[]>[] Attachments { get; }
        string AttachmentFileName { get; }
        string HtmlBody { get; }
        string Subject { get; set; }
        string TextBody { get; }
        IEnumerable<IEmailAddress> To { get; }
    }
```

Consuming the message:

```
        if (context.Message.Attachment.HasValue)
        {
            var attachmentData = await context.Message.Attachment.Value;
        }

        if (context.Message.Attachments.AnySafe())
        {
            foreach (MessageData<byte[]> messageAttachment in context.Message.Attachments)
            {
                byte[] data = await messageAttachment.Value;
                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Attachment size: {data.Length}");
            }
        }
```

The single MessageData<byte[]> is working fine, but when I try to get the data from the collection I get the Exception.

Comment: I think sending collections of MessageData is not supported.